# Parsing followings from Instagram

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

I have some accounts, and I should get it's followings.
I try to use `requests`

```
for username in usernames_list:
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + username + '/following/'
    page = requests.get(url).content
```

And I have thought that I can get page with followings and next parsing names of this pages.
But it returns start page and I can't open page of followings.
Is any way to parse followings from the instagram?

Comment: Please edit your question following [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/username/following/ redirects to https://www.instagram.com/username/, perhaps try the Instagram API https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Look into this specific API https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is required to be logged in to Instagram to obtain this kind of information, which might explain why it is not so easy to get them with one simple JSON query.

The [Instaloader package](https://instaloader.github.io/) provides a convenient way to login and then programmatically access a profile's followees (followings).

```
import instaloader

# Get instance
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
L.login(USER, PASSWORD)        # (login)
L.interactive_login(USER)      # (ask password on terminal)
L.load_session_from_file(USER) # (load session created w/
                               #  `instaloader -l USERNAME`)

# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)

# Print list of followees
for followee in profile.get_followees():
    print(followee.username)
```

Besides `username`, the attributes `full_name`, `userid`, `followed_by_viewer` and many more are defined in the `Profile` instance that is returned for each followee.